# create Set in Django with the Soundcloud API

Tags: python, api, widget, embed, soundcloud

I am trying to experiment with the soundcloud player, but when I use the code from the API tutorial I get the following error: 'Resource' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'`

I don't see why embed_info['html'] wouldn't work when it's exactly what's said on https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing.  I am trying to make a page that will create a set from track objects I have inventoried on my website.

```
def sc(request):
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='my_id')

    # get a tracks oembed data
    track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood'
    embed_info = client.get('/oembed', url=track_url)

    # print the html for the player widget
    print embed_info['html']

    return render(request, 'rango/sc.html', {'embed' : embed_info})
```

Comment: wha is `embed_info` at that point (e.g. look at it in the debugger..)

Comment: @Rob, just so you know, your client id is still in the revision history.  I'd suggest you generate a new one if it's sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `Resource` object in the soundcloud-python [github repo](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/resource.py#L9), it appears their documentation is out of date.

`Resource` defines a `__getattr__` method but not a `__getitem__` method. This means you will have to use dot notation to access the values you are interested in rather than slice notation. Changing:

```
print embed_info['html']
```

to

```
print embed_info.html
```

outputs:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=https%3A%2F
%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F293&show_artwork=true&
client_id=96e00f360883e6ef77c531acfc8ee4c3"></iframe>
```

which I believe is what you are looking for.

**Edit**:

To embed a Set instead of a Track, you just call `client.get` with the `url` parameter set to the URL of the playlist in question. To get the `oembed` data for the Playlist with id `405726`:

```
def sc(request):
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='my_id')

    # get a playlist's oembed data
    playlist_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/405726"
    embed_info = client.get('/oembed', url=playlist_url)

    # print the html for the player widget
    print embed_info.html

    return render(request, 'rango/sc.html', {'embed' : embed_info})
```

**Edit 2**:

On the topic of getting an embed for an arbitrary set of tracks:

You can query for multiple unrelated tracks in a single request using the `ids` query parameter on the `/tracks` endpoint. It accepts a comma separated list of track ids. Usage:

```
$ curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&ids=13158665,6621631"
```

returns a list containing track 13158665 and 6621631.

Unfortunately, a) this request cannot be recreated using the client with either `client.get('/tracks', ids='13158665,6621631')` or `client.get('/tracks?ids=13158665,6621631')` directly or just by passing the URL we successfully `curl`ed as the url paramater to `client.get('/oembed', url=our_clever_url)`.

At the very least, we have discovered a limitation of the Fortunately, we can always drop down outside the provided client to test whether we can do what we need to. Using the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, we can query the API itself, sans wrapper:

```
import requests

client_id='my-id'

track_ids = ["13158665", "6621631"]
tracks_url ='http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks'

payload = {'client_id': client_id, 'ids': ','.join(track_ids)}
response = requests.get(tracks_url, params=payload)
print response.status_code
print response.json()
```

So we can at the very least manually retrieve an arbitrary group of tracks in one request by id.

Now the question is: will the `/oembed` endpoint accept a URL with an `ids` query parameter and respond accordingly? Still need to test that, will update again in a moment.

**Edit 3**:

I was able to get the `/oembed` endpoint to return XML manually when I only wanted a single track/playlist (passed via resource URL as the `url` query parameter), and previously I'd been able to retrieve multiple individual tracks via the `/tracks` endpoint using the `ids` query parameter. Unfortunately, the `/oembed` endpoint does not support retrieving an arbitrary set of track ids. You'll have to try something else.

Comment: thankyou for the swift response.  Do you have any advice on how to generate a Set?  If I had links to https://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood and https://soundcloud.com/forss/veniam and wanted to create a playlist from them is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Thank you again.  This does not generate a playlist though, my aim is to generate a playlist based upon a library of songs I have, and so I would want to create the set from tracks based on user input.

Comment: @Rob Do you want all of a single user's tracks or an arbitrary set of tracks?

Comment: arbitrary tracks, like I would have a library of tracks, user would give me input, and I would create a playlist with four tracks that I recommend together.  So it would be different every time.

Comment: @Rob sorry to disappear for a while, was experimenting with this. It is not possible using the Python SDK directly. I was able to approximate it by making raw requests, however. Editing answer now with what I found; check that out.